# How can i add Three20 to my project using Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, three20

I want to add Three20 to my project in Xcode 4.2 and it gives me these warnings:

[image]

[image]

Is there anyone who has a tutorial to add Three20 to the project using Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on terminal

```
> python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/your/project/project.xcodeproj Three20
```

**Steps:**

```
1) Open Terminal
2) type "python"
3) Locate "ttmodule.py" file & drag it on Terminal
4) -p
5) locate your project xcode file & drag to terminal
6) Three20
7)Press enter Three20 will be added to your project
```

**Another way:**

```
1)Open your project
2)Open three20 xcode project
3) drag three20 project in your project
```